# Git submodules for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, git-submodules

I have this question for days but i cant find any answers on the internet.

Is it possible to add a submodule too wordpress and too its wp content folder so you can update wordpress without updating the wp config folder and everything what is inside of it?

Comment: Use a .gitignore file that contains the root of the config folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question nor the thoughts behind it. Theoretically it is possible to add git submodules, but this hasn't something to do with WordPress. WordPress doesn't matter if it's a git submodule or not.

I already used git submodules for WordPress Themes and that wasn't any problem.

Just to clarify: wp-config.php is a file, not a folder. When you update WordPress it is very important that the wp-includes folder etc. is writeable. If not the update will fail.

When you don't want to include some files into git, use the .gitignore file.

Can you explain what you really want to achive with the submodules?

Comment: I am sorry i miss wrote myself, instead of wp config folder i meant wp content folder. This is because i want to update my wordpress site but i dont want to update all my content this because of some changes i did too plugins and they will overwrite it when they got updated.

Comment: Okay, even with submodules the WordPress will overwrite your changes when you make an update. I would suggest the plugin [block updates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-specific-plugin-updates/) to prevent WordPress from updating your plugins. WordPress updates never update anything within the wp-content folder. Just theme- and plugin updates do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will see what the plugin can do for me.